# QTP locked cells cannot modified

Tags: datatable, automated-tests, qtp

for whom using QTP(Quick Test Professional) do anyone of you face this issue on data table upon savin script on QC(Quality Center).

When you try to edit "DataTable" message box says that "locked cells cannot modified" displays.
kindly see the attached snapshot.[image]

your help and support is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manaysah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that the following procedure corrects this problem:

1. Open the test in QTP
2. Check it out
3. Right-click the datatable
4. Select File > Export…
5. Browse to the location where you want to save the export file
6. Enter a file name for the export file
7. Click Save
8. Right-click the datatable
9. Select File > Import
10. Browse to the location where you saved the export file
11. Select the export file
12. Click OK

Datatable should now be unlocked.

Comment: Damn. After years and years of QC+QTP development, they are unable to keep their db consistent. *H*ead *P*awn

Answer (score 3):

If you are using QC 10.0 to store/save your QTP 10.0 scripts ,then you can try following.

- Verify what patch level your QC 10.o on if you are on patch 28 then you have to apply patch 29 on QC.
- Defect ID: QCCR1J 24598
- Problem: An automatic job runs every fifteen minutes that cleans the database of stale sessions and locks.
- A regression prevents locks from being deleted if the Quality Center client was terminated abruptly.
- This causes entities to remain locked even after the LOCK_TIMEOUT and the entities cannot be edited.
- A workaround existed to physically delete the locked rows from the database

Comment: Thanks Dam, But i dont understand how to do that. 
do u have a more detailed steps how to unlock ?

Comment: +1 for adding these details. Maker of the software is *H*opefully *P*romising